# Creating event reminders

Tags: ionic-framework

I am working on an ionic project. It is based on medication managing.And I want to remind the user about their medications. I am new to this and can some one give me a sample code, link or something to create reminders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend taking a look at Local Notifications, they are notifications that can be scheduled on the device without the need for a server. It is commonly used for things like reminders. You can also choose to do this using a server with Push Notifications, but that doesn't seem necessary in your situation.

For starters, take a look at the [documentation for Local Notifications](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications), see if it works for your use case.